# OpenVPN server only gives username/password and client requires certificates

Tags: vpn, openvpn

We have a eFive OpenVPN server which gives me a CA cert, usernames and passwords for the account. In addition, I have a RUT550 LTE router, from Teltonika, whose OpenVPN client setting allows static authentication, or TLS authentication, the latter of which allows me to put in a CA cert and client certificate and key.

Is it possible to use the username and password authentication method provided to me, to use/convert to a client certificate and key? If so, could you please let me know how this would be possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not seeing any options in the [manual](http://www.induowireless.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/lte-router-rut-550-teltonika.pdf) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

Client certificates have to be created by a ca the openvpn server trusts.

**Update**:
I now had a look at the eFive docs. It seems like eFive OpenVPN Appliance only supports password authentication for clients.
OpenVPN supports client certificates, password authentification and using both together.
And, as I saw looking at the RUT550 docs: PreShared-Key auth, which is not a solution for your problem.

So the answer is: 
Your devices are both based on OpenVPN, but they are not compatible.

For creating client certs you need the private key (not just the public certificate) of the CA.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Guess there's not much I can do. I'll try and setup a software VPN of sorts then.

Answer (score 1):

Use the eFive OpenVPN CA cert to create cleint certs. You can not create client certs from username and password. There are utilities for managing certs. 'x509-util' and 'xca' packages are available on Ubuntu. Search for x509 utilities for other platforms.

Comment: Thanks Nizam, but am I to assume that I cannot use any form of user authentication then? We have multiple systems, each with its own IP ranges, based on the login.